# How to train the neural network with small dataset or how to make huge dataset without human intervention?

Tags: neural-network, robotics, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train the robot for specific actions such as grasping or pointing by using the RNN. 
The robot is composed of one arm and a head containing camera in it. Also the workspace will be the small table so that the arm and objects can be located. 
The input of the recurrent neural network wiil be the image frame of every time steps from the camera and the output will be the target motor angle of next frame of the robot arm. 
When the current image frame is fed to the network, the network outputs the motor value of arm for the next frame. And when the arm reaches the next position, the input frame in that position is again goes to the network and it again yields the next motor output.

However, when making the data for training, I have to make all the data of (image, motor angle) pair for all the position on the workspace. Eventhough the network can do some generalization job by itselt, the data needed is stil too much and it takes lots of time since there are too many trajectories.

Generalizing the problem I have, the time for getting training data for network is too much. Is there any way or method that can train network with small size dataset? Or making huge dataset within relatively small human intervention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very broad and definitely encompasses more than field of study. This question cannot be answered in this platform, however, i suggest you to check out this [compilation of Machine Learning Resources](https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning/blob/master/README.md) on gitHub, specifically **Data Analysis** section.

A more specific resource related to your question is [DeepNeuralClassifier](https://github.com/jostmey/DeepNeuralClassifier).

Answer (score 0):

I searched more paper and I found some that are related to the subject. The main topic of my question was to

1. find the way to train the network efficiently with small size of dataset
2. find the way to make huge dataset with small human effort

There were some papers and two of them helped me a lot. This is the link.

[Explanation-Based Neural Network Learning for Robot Control](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1.9632&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

[Supersizing Self-supervision: Learning to Grasp from 50K Tries and 700 Robot Hours](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06825v1.pdf)